# Loud grinding sound from gearbox

Tags: transmission

We've replaced the old clutch on our Toyota Land cruiser prado 2002 to a new one and when we put in gear there's a very loud noise, it sounds like a chain spinning all around coming from the gearbox. I need help. *Excuse my english.

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind: one the clutch centre plate is reversed or two the input shaft bearing has also failed...

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bad work from your mechanic. He must have done something wrong when he hooked up the clutch with transmission. It needs a professional check.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Possible improperly adjusted master cylinder rod.  Or perhaps the master and/or slave cylinder decided to pack it up.  Could also be a bent shift fork.  Less likely is a defective or improperly stepped clutch (I've seen that happen just once before).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the clutch is not fully disengaging the transmission. So, when you shift you are still transmitting power to the transmission and the dogteeth are spinning too fast relative to each other. The clutch needs to be fixed, and it could be multiple things, from the hydraulics (cheap) to having to replace/reinstall the whole clutch again (expensive). But if you just had the clutch replaced, then I would take it back.